# Can anyone explain the meaning and usage of POJO or POCO

Tags: c#, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the term Plain Old Java Object(POJO) exactly mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326319/what-does-the-term-plain-old-java-objectpojo-exactly-mean)

I know those are recent concepts proposed by Mark Fowler. can anyone explain what the purpose of POJO or POCO and their usage?

Comment: Where did you learn who proposed them, but not what they *mean*? Oh, and it was [Martin Fowler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Fowler) who proposed those names.

Comment: It means "Plain Old [Language] Object". Really, you can trivially search and discover this answer and more details for yourself.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**P** lain **O** ld ( **J** ava,/ **C** LR ) **O** bject

It's just a fancy name for a very basic class structure<sup>[1](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/POJO.html)</sup>.

> *[...]We wondered why people were so against using regular objects in their systems and concluded that it was because simple objects lacked a fancy name. So we gave them one[...]*

Answer (score 16):

It stands for **Plain Old [Java|CLR] Object**, and it means pretty much what it says - a simple object that doesn't require any significant "guts" to make it work. The idea is in contrast with very dependent objects that have a hard time being (or can't be) instantiated and manipulated on their own - they require other services, drivers, provider instances, etc. to also be present.

Here's an example of a c# POCO:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the hypothetical innards of a hypothetical non-POCO:

```
public sealed class Customer
{
    //can only be created by a db service layer
    internal Customer(IDbContext databaseContext)
    {
    }

    [EntityMapping("Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return context.HydrateValue(this, "Name");
        }
        set
        {
            InternalNotifyRevision("Name", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

POCO stands for [Plain Old CLR Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) and POJO for [Plain Old Java Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object).